# JS to define function only loading on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, gfycat

[Gfycat](https://github.com/gfycat/gfycat.js) has a javascript library that enables embeding on my website written in Rails with a div like this:

`<div class="gfyitem" data-autoplay=false data-id="BestYellowishElephantseal"></div>`

To do this it tells me to add their script after the opening body tag.

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://assets.gfycat.com/gfycat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'gfycat-js'));
</script>
```

However, when adding it inside the body tag it only loads when hard refreshing the page. I tested this by adding a `console.log("Gfycat Loaded");` inside the function.

After some googling it seems like this has to do with turbolinks, and I have had some issues with this before.

The solution to this has been to add the JS inside:

```
ready = ->
    # Code here
$(document).on "page:change", -> ready()
$(document).on "page:restore", -> ready()
```

So I tried adding the gfycat function inside the document ready, but get exactly the same result.

Anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: wrap yr Gfy in to one function name it as u want "xxxx3", `$(xxxx3); $(document).on("turbolinks:load", xxxx3);` try this one and let me know.

Comment: Does not work. I'm on Rails 4.2.5. `turbolinks:load` does nothing. But if i try to use `page:load` at least a alert("Hi") in the function called triggers.

Comment: After some more debugging it seems like the library does get loaded. If I write gfyCollection in the Crome console it does get recognized. If I write gfyCollection.init() the gfycat gets loaded, but without the video sources inside the video element for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what the code I'm testing with at the moment:
https://jsfiddle.net/99f6soxy/

On hard refresh I get:

```
Page loaded
Library got called
```

On clicking a link I only get:

```
Page loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, like this ?

```
<script>    
  function gfycatInit(){
    function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "https://assets.gfycat.com/gfycat.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'gfycat-js');
    }
  }
  $(gfycatInit);
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", gfycatInit);
</script>
```